# Define a Callable with arguments in constructor using Lambda expression

Tags: lambda, java-8, callable

I am trying to rewrite the following Callable implementation using a Lambda expression:

```
    public class NLQueryTask implements Callable<NLQuery> {
    private String questionText, languageTranslationModelId;

    public NLQueryTask(String questionText, String languageTranslationModelId) {
        this.questionText = questionText;
        this.languageTranslationModelId = languageTranslationModelId;
    }

    @Override
    public NLQuery call() throws Exception {...}
```

I get a compiler error if I try to include the parameters in the Lambda expression:

```
Callable<Integer> task = (String questionText, languageTranslationModelId) -> {...
```

Obviously I am missing something (I started reading about Lambda expressions today). How should I define the Lambda expression so it does not use the default Callable constructor (no arguments) but the arguments my routine needs?

Thanks

Comment: A callable takes no arguments when called i.e. it has one method `call()` If you want to use values available when the callable is created you can just refer to them and they will be captured.

Answer (score 3):

The lambda expression is modeled after the single abstract method in the target interface, `Callable#call()` in this case. This method has an empty parameter list. The parameter list of the lambda expression must then also be empty.

You can capture the value that you would've passed as arguments to the `NLQueryTask` constructor within the lambda body.

```
String questionText = "some text";
String languageTranslationModelId = "1234";

Callable<Integer> task = () -> {
    System.out.println(questionText);
    return Integer.parseInt(languageTranslationModelId); // whatever
};
```

Obviously, local variables captured have to be effectively `final`.